# method to return largest integer c#

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with this method return of the largest integer, compiler says no errors but it won't let me run it

Comment: What do you mean by "won't let me run it"?

Comment: Your code is damaged, it matters where the `{}` from ButtonClick are. Caopy/Paste real code .

Comment: "compiler says no errors" - I find that a bit hard to believe.

Comment: That said, where do you think you are calling your method?

Comment: Are you aware there is a Math.Max function in C#?

Comment: I think you need to follow a tutorial on C# or something. This is full of syntax errors.

Comment: CODE IS NOT CORRECT.. Method is out of Class and look at the call of private method in `calcButton_Click`

Answer (score 1):

I have no clear idea what you are asking for.. I think at one time you had code but it is now gone?

Anyway, here is a console example for making an array and displaying its max value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare i
        int i;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 random numbers");
        //Make some array
        string[] numbers = new string[5];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("\nEnter your number:\t");
            //Storing value in an array
            numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //ta da your array is now completed.. lets see what is the largest..
        var converted = numbers.Select(int.Parse);
        int largest = converted.Max();
        //ta da
        Console.WriteLine("The largest number is..." + (largest));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Also, as cheap looking as this site is.. it isn't that bad.. I would strongly encourage you to go through it http://www.completecsharptutorial.com/basic/getting-started.php